# Angular directive for Date Picker triggering after second focus

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular4-forms

I am making a angular directive for datepicker. It is not working as required, the date picker triggers when i focus second time in the input box. Below is the code for the same.

**Directive**

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

declare const $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDatePicker]'
})
export class DatePickerDirective {

  constructor() {

  }

  @HostListener('focus') onFocus() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true
    });
  }

}
```

**It's use in component**

```
 <input appDatePicker type="text" required name="title" 
class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="01/01/2018">
```

I am using Bootstrap datepicker for this. [Link](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)

**Form HTML**

```
<form role="form" #createForm="ngForm">

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Occasion<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <div class="col-7">
                <input type="text" name="code" required [(ngModel)]="holiday.occasion" class="form-control"
                       placeholder="New Year">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <div class="col-7">
                <input appDatePicker type="text" required name="title" [(ngModel)]="holiday.off_date" class="date-picker form-control"
                       placeholder="01/01/2018">

              </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-7 offset-4">
                <button (click)="store()" type="submit" [disabled]="!createForm.form.valid || actionRecordLoader"
                        class="btn btn-purple waves-effect waves-light">
                  <span *ngIf="!actionRecordLoader">Create</span>
                  <app-button-loader *ngIf="actionRecordLoader"></app-button-loader>
                </button>
                <button type="reset"
                        class="btn btn-light waves-effect m-l-5">
                  Reset
                </button>
                <app-back-button></app-back-button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-7 offset-4">
                <ul>
                  <li class="text-danger" *ngFor="let error of errors | keyValueConvert">{{error.value}}</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried registering widget once and in ngAfterViewInit hook rather than do it every time focus event happens?

Comment: @yurzui how to do register this widget?? Can you help with that?

Comment: @yurzui i suppose directive don't have that kind of hooks. Am i right?

Comment: It has, you can also do it in ngOnInit

Comment: @yurzui its working. Thanks!!

Comment: @yurzui I am using required attribute for disabling the create button.  When select a value from date-picker it doesn't enable the button but it does when i type.

Comment: Either implement ControlValueAccessor or just try to fire ngModelChange event when you choose something in datepicker

Comment: @yurzui I am extremely confused how to that. Sorry for bothering so much i am new to angular.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709822/angular-bind-date-picked-from-bootstrap-datepicker-to-underlying-ngmodel-or-for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168967/discussion-between-abhishek-and-yurzui).